# Hide tap jacking alerts on android app below Android 12

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-security, android-securityexception

I want to hide tap-jacking alerts in my Android app. I was able to do it on Android 12 and above by using `getWindow().setHideOverlayWindows(true);`. Can someone help me achieve this on versions below Android 12? Is there any alternative method to setHideOverlayWindows(true) for versions below Android 12?

I also added below property in xml's rootview.

```
android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Before Android 12, there's only one permission
[android.permission.HIDE_NON_SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOWS](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml;drc=3d3e54aae76da63c2b2a592247393dbd40aa385b;l=4719) which is intended for system app.

so basicly there's no trivial way to do that